# Can adding of attribute table fields cause geoDB replica fail

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, replication

We have a arcsde replica between 2 sql server geoDB, it is one way replica and our side is the child. Recently our scheduler to synchronize the replica failed.

The parent side add fields in some layers attribute table, but they insist only the removal of the attribute fields can cause the replica synchronize fail, additional of fields should not affect the replication.

Before I compare the replica schema, I want to confirm whether the adding of attribute fields can cause the replication fail.

Both the parent and child side using arcsde 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

Look into this article. It explains how to apply schema changes with replicas and sync those changes back to the parent.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000t2000000